# Flushedleft title with maketitle aligned at right margin of marginparwidth

Tags: positioning, margins, titles, alignment, layout

after fixing my [footnote-problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686421/need-footnote-enclosed-by-horizontal-line-above-and-below/686504#686504) I work on the title layout.

The journal needs an title with flushed-left content, but the "titlebox" itself should align at the right margin of the `marginparwidth`-area. The layout of the journal has a very broad margin.

My MWE offers the needed layout of the title-content:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,
twoside,%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{noto}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    inner=2cm,
    outer=4cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    marginparwidth=3cm,
}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{jogagray}{RGB}{81, 83, 74}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
    \apptocmd{\@title}{\par \vskip 0.5em {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{flushright}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}%
            \begin{flushleft}%
                \let \footnote \thanks
                {%\begin{spacing}{1.5} 
                \large \color{jogagray} \@author 
                %\end{spacing}
                }%
                \vskip 1em
                {\color{jogagray} \hrule \@width\columnwidth height 10pt \par}%
                \vskip 1em%
                {\Huge \color{jogagray} \sffamily \@title \par}%
                \vskip 1.5em%
            \end{flushleft}%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{flushright}%
    \par
    \vskip 8em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Title}
\subtitle{A Subtitle}
\author{An Author, Another Author, A Third Author, A Last Author}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

But the title itself should be aligned at the right margin of `marginparwidth`, like the arrow shows in the image:

[image: Position of the title]

The used code should possibly use mostly basic commands and/or primitives, because it has to be usable with different Latex-classes.

Thanks in advance for possible solutions.

Comment: I know that the `@maketitle` redefinition makes trouble if I add multiple authors with `\and`, maybe i redefine `\and`, so there occurs no problems. But thats not part of this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add horizontal space before the minipage, with a total width of `0.2\textwidth + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth` to offset the "titlebox" to the right margin of the margin space.

Note the `%` right after the `\hspace*(...}` to avoid spurious spaces.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,
twoside,
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{noto}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    inner=2cm,
    outer=4cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    marginparwidth=3cm,
    showframe % to show the margins <<<<<<<
}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{jogagray}{RGB}{81, 83, 74}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
    \apptocmd{\@title}{\par \vskip 0.5em {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{flushright}%
        \hspace*{\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}%
                \parindent0pt
            \begin{flushleft}%
                \let \footnote \thanks
                {%\begin{spacing}{1.5} 
                    \large \color{jogagray} \@author 
                    %\end{spacing}
                }%
                \vskip 1em
                {\color{jogagray} \hrule\@width\textwidth height 10pt \par}%%changed <<<<
                \vskip 1em%
                {\Huge \color{jogagray} \sffamily \@title \par}%
                \vskip 1.5em%
            \end{flushleft}%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{flushright}%
    \par
    \vskip 8em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Title}
\subtitle{A Subtitle}
\author{An Author, Another Author, A Third Author, A Last Author}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!